# Asignar un string como referencia a otro string dentro de un objeto

Tags: c#, unity

Estoy algo confuso intentando hacer lo siguiente y espero que puedan ayudarme.

Tengo una clase con una serie de strings:

```
public class Ejemplo{
    private string nombre;
    private string id;
    private string descripcion;
    ...
}
```

Lo que necesito es clonar este objeto pero manteniendo la referencia de ciertos `strings` al original. Para ello tengo un método `Clone()` que me devuelve una copia del objeto:

```
public object Clone(){
    Ejemplo ejemplo = new Ejemplo();
    ejemplo.nombre = this.nombre;
    ejemplo.id = this.id;
    ejemplo.descripcion = this.descripcion;
    ...

    return ejemplo;
}
```

Y luego hay otras variables que si que las inicializo como un nuevo objeto ya que me interesa que sean independientes (de ahí hacer la copia). Al hacerlo de esta manera consigo hacer bien la copia, pero al modificar el objeto original no consigo que se repliquen estos cambios en la copia.

Lo que querría es que si cambio el nombre u otros `strings` en el objeto original se cambie también en la copia. Ahora mismo me hace esto:

```
Ejemplo ejemplo = new Ejemplo();
ejemplo.nombre = "Hola";
Ejemplo ejemplo2 = ejemplo.Clone();
Console.WriteLine(ejemplo.nombre);   // Muestra "Hola"
Console.WriteLine(ejemplo2.nombre);  // Muestra "Hola"

ejemplo.nombre = "Adios";
Console.WriteLine(ejemplo.nombre);   // Muestra "Adios"
Console.WriteLine(ejemplo2.nombre);  // Muestra "Hola"
```

Y Lo que querría conseguir es esto:

```
Ejemplo ejemplo = new Ejemplo();
ejemplo.nombre = "Hola";
Ejemplo ejemplo2 = ejemplo.Clone();
Console.WriteLine(ejemplo.nombre);   // Muestra "Hola"
Console.WriteLine(ejemplo2.nombre);  // Muestra "Hola"

ejemplo.nombre = "Adios";
Console.WriteLine(ejemplo.nombre);   // Muestra "Adios"
Console.WriteLine(ejemplo2.nombre);  // Muestra "Adios"
```

He intentado asignarlo con `ejemplo.name = String.Intern(this.name);` pero me sigue pasando lo mismo.

¿Alguna idea de como podría hacer esto, que concepto me esta fallando o si es posible hacerlo? Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Te esta fallando el concepto de que los strings no son punteros, son cadenas. Si generas una nueva cadena, no es un puntero a la cadena anterior, es una nueva cadena. Y clonar el objeto, clona sus propiedades tambien. Para hacer lo que queres hacer deberias generar clases que mantengan las referencias a los mismos objetos...

Comment: El objetivo de tu método `Clone()` es copiar por valor los valores de los atributos de un objeto y asignárselas a los atributos de otro.

Comment: @gbianchi esa es la idea, mantener referencias al original pero solo con ciertas variables, y no se me ocurre como hacerlo. CryogenicNeo, ese es el objetivo, pero solo quiero que pase con otras variables, que estarían donde puse los puntos suspensivos.

Comment: usa objetos que contengan solo las variables que necesitas. y copia esos objetos como referencia. Igual, es raro que quieras hacer algo asi, tal vez con un poco mas de explicacion de porque piensas que esta es la solucion a tu problema, podamos ver si realmente es lo que necesitas

Comment: Vale, llevo todo el día trabajando con esto y no se me había ocurrido una solución tan sencilla. Puedo crear un nuevo objeto que contenga solo las variables que necesito cambiar y una referencia al objeto original, y así puedo usar las variables que necesite del original llamando a éste, que tendrá los cambios que realice al original. Creo que es la solución. Voy a probar aunque me llevará bastante tiempo cambiar todo. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta crear las siguientes **clases**:

- **Una clase de referencia:** en esta clases vas a definir todas las propiedades que quieras cambiar vía referencia.
- **Una clase que solo comparta la referencia de la clase original:** en esta clase vas a definir simplemente la clase con la que compartiras las referencias y las propiedades que solo quieres que cambien con la referencia de la clase.

Por ejemplo:

```
public class Data {

    public DataReference Reference { get; set; }
    public string Stage { get; set; }

    public Data(){
         this.Reference = new DataReference();
    }

    public Data ShallowCopy() {
         return this.MemberwiseClone() as Data;
    }
}

public class DataReference {
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public DataReference(){ }
}
```

Las pruebas definen la siguiente salida:

```
// Defines los valores iniciales antes de clonar el objeto original
Data data = new Data();
data.Reference.Username = "ZenzukyLzC";
data.Reference.Level = 150;
data.Stage = "Prologue";

Data cloneData = data.ShallowCopy(); // Clonas el objeto

Console.WriteLine(data.Reference.Username); // imprime "ZenzukyLzc"
Console.WriteLine(cloneData.Reference.Username); // Imprime "ZenzukyLzC"
Console.WriteLine(data.Reference.Level); // imprime 150
Console.WriteLine(cloneData.Reference.Level); // Imprime 150
Console.WriteLine(data.Stage); // imprime "Prologue"
Console.WriteLine(cloneData.Stage); // Imprime "Prologue"

data.Reference.Username = "Uzi-Zenzuky";
data.Reference.Level = 151;
data.Stage = "Stage one";

Console.WriteLine(data.Reference.Username); // imprime "Uzi-Zenzuky"
Console.WriteLine(cloneData.Reference.Username); // Imprime "Uzi-Zenzuky"
Console.WriteLine(data.Reference.Level); // imprime 151
Console.WriteLine(cloneData.Reference.Level); // Imprime 151
Console.WriteLine(data.Stage); // imprime "Stage One"
Console.WriteLine(cloneData.Stage); // Imprime "Prologue"

cloneData.Reference.Username = "NenoZky";
cloneData.Reference.Level = 152;
cloneData.Stage = "Stage Two";

Console.WriteLine(data.Reference.Username); // imprime "NenoZky"
Console.WriteLine(cloneData.Reference.Username); // Imprime "NenoZky"
Console.WriteLine(data.Reference.Level); // imprime 152
Console.WriteLine(cloneData.Reference.Level); // Imprime 152
Console.WriteLine(data.Stage); // imprime "Stage One"
Console.WriteLine(cloneData.Stage); // Imprime "Stage Two"
```

Si te fijas, los valores que estan en `Reference` cambian junto con cualquier referencia de `Data`. Mientras los que son propios de `Data`, solo cambian en el objeto en particular.

Mas info: [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Esta respuesta es perfecta, justo lo que buscaba, gracias! Es exactamente lo que estaba haciendo gracias a los comentarios de @gbianchi. Eso si, he tenido que cambiar muchas referencias al no haberlo planificado bien desde el principio, pero ya esta funcionando. Gracias a todos los que habéis contestado por la ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

Para poder pasar valores por referencia o crear variables u objetos que sean referencia de otras variables o valores necesitas usar la palabra clave `ref`.

Con la palabra `ref` indicas referencia en el momento de declarar variables u objetos de clases.

En esta [página](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) del sitio de Microsoft MSDN nos hablan del uso de la palabra `ref`. Nos dan un ejemplo de cómo usarlo con objetos o estructuras:

```
ref VeryLargeStruct reflocal = ref veryLargeStruct;
```

Por lo tanto, para pasar una objeto como referencia a otro y de esta manera manejar las mismas variables, por ejemplo para este caso, puedes usar este código:

```
Ejemplo ejemplo = new Ejemplo();
ejemplo.nombre = "Hola";
ref Ejemplo ejemplo2 = ref ejemplo;
Console.WriteLine(ejemplo.nombre);   // Muestra "Hola"
Console.WriteLine(ejemplo2.nombre);  // Muestra "Hola"

ejemplo.nombre = "Adios";
Console.WriteLine(ejemplo.nombre);   // Muestra "Adios"
Console.WriteLine(ejemplo2.nombre);  // Muestra "Adios"
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:** Para poder pasar por referencia variables como parámetros de funciones puedes usar la palabra reservada `out`. `out` hace que los argumentos se pasen por referencia, de esta manera podrás modificar tu método `Clone()` para que pase por referencia un objeto y sus atributos. Para esto debes hacer el método estático y poner como parámetros tu objeto a clonar y el objeto clonado.

Por ejemplo:

```
public static void Clone(Ejemplo ejemplo, out Ejemplo ejemplo2){
    // De esta manera asignarás los atributos del objeto que 
    // quieras que sean pasados por referencia.
    ejemplo2.nombre = ejemplo.nombre;
    ejemplo2.id = ejemplo.id;
    ejemplo2.descripcion = ejemplo.descripcion;
    ...
}
```

Esto debe funcionar para resolver tu problema.

Aquí está la página del sitio de Microsoft MSDN que habla del uso de `ref` y `out`:

[ref (Referencia de C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref)

[Modificador del parámetro out (Referencia de C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier)

Comment: Este proyecto está creado para funcionar en `Unity` y no me deja usar estas referencias por la versión de C#, me dice lo siguiente: `La funcionalidad 'variables locales y devoluciones por referencia' no está disponible en C#4. Use la versión de idioma 7 u otra superior.`

Comment: Debiste haber especificado que se trata de esa versión del lenguaje y que iba dirigido hacia Unity. Por favor, modifica tu pregunta.

Comment: Ya están modificadas las etiquetas, pensé que la ultima versión de `Unity` utilizaría también la última versión de `C#`. Agradezco y puntuó tu respuesta de todos modos, gracias.

Comment: Prueba asignando directamente el un objeto a otro, es decir: `Ejemplo ejemplo2 = ejemplo;`. Para Unity, según esta [respuesta](http://answers.unity.com/answers/1292005/view.html), todos los objetos se pasan por referencia por defecto.

Comment: Si, pero si lo hago así se guardan todas las referencias, lo que quiero es mantener solo ciertas variables por referencia y las otras como copia. Por ejemplo, que si cambio la variable `nombre` se modifique en todos los objetos clonados pero si cambio la variable `cantidad` solo se modifique en ese y no en todas las copias del original.

Comment: @Wyrncael Ahí te he actualizado la respuesta con el modificador `out`. Revisa la respuesta y me indicas lo útil que te fue. :D